# What does “nod soberly” means?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The sentence is more or less like this:

> You notice the poor screenwriter with cheap clothes and bloodshot eyes, eating alone at the corner of the room. Your eyes meet. You nod at him with respect. He nods soberly back at you.

I’m confused with the word “soberly” here because I’m not under any impression that the screenwriter is drunk or high. What does “nod soberly” here means?

Comment: It's interesting to speculate on how many writers actually [made the specific choice](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nodded+soberly%2Cnodded+somberly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnodded%20soberly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnodded%20somberly%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnodded%20soberly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnodded%20somberly%3B%2Cc0) between ***soberly*** and ***somberly*** after ***nodded*** on semantic grounds. As you can see from that link, they're both pretty common.

Comment: See all the meanings of 'sober', for example [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sober). Only the first is about "not being drunk".

Comment: ...anyway, in practice, ***sober*** and ***sombre*** have very similar connotations for this context. Arguably ***sober*** carries stronger allusions to ***grave, serious*** (but ***not*** "emotional") where ***sombre*** is more evocative of ***gloomy, dismal*** (a strongly *negative* emotional state). The idea of "not being drunk" isn't really what it's all about here.

Comment: Thank you all for the information. At least this gives me context about how to interpret the soberly.